# If a set $X$ is convex and its complement $X^c$ is convex, then the boundary is a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analysis, convex-analysis

Prove that in $\mathbb R^n$:

> If a set $X$ is convex and its complement $X^c$ is convex and non-empty, then the boundary is a hyperplane.

It seems really obvious intuitively. However proving this involves at least one page of work for me. Are there any theorem that I can cite/refer to?

Comment: About the validity of the claim, in infinite dimension there is the issue that you may have a discontinuous functional $\phi$ which determines two dense complementary convex sets $\phi^{-1}[0,\infty)$ and $\phi^{-1}(-\infty,0)$. At that point, the boundary of either won't be a hyperplane, but the whole space.

Comment: @Gae.S. The typical setting for this type of problem is $\mathbb R^n$, so I don't think the infinite dimensional case is too worrisome.

Comment: You'll need that neither $X$ nor $X^C$ are empty.

Comment: @OlivierRoche I thought a null set is a hyperplane?

Comment: a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n-1$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche Oh, ok. I appreciate it. Question edited by the way.

Comment: @user293203 In infinite dimensions, can we claim that $X$ and $X^c$ are half space instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any theorem for that, but I have a relatively simple argument:

If $X$ is convex, then it can be written as the intersection of a family $\mathcal F$ of half-spaces (i.e. the part of the space on one side of a hyperplane). Similarly, $X^c$ can also be written as the intersection of another family $\mathcal G$ of half-spaces.

Now I claim that for any element $F\in \mathcal F$ and any element $G\in \mathcal G$, the corresponding hyperplanes must be parallel. This is because the union $F\cup G$ contains $X\cup X^c$, which is the whole space.

Consequently, assuming $X$ is neither empty nor the whole space, all cutting-hyperplanes in the family $\mathcal F$ are parallel, and similarly for $\mathcal G$. This implies that $X$ is a half-space.

---

I somehow ignored the difference between "open" and "closed" half-spaces, but this is unimportant, and we can of course change the condition to the closures of $X$ and $X^c$ being convex.

Comment: Of course this answer is correct, though I thought there must exist a simple proof for a simple statement like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a separation argument: the sets $X,X^c$ are both convex and non-empty, in addition $X \cap X^c=\emptyset$. So there is a separating hyperplane, i.e., there exists $a\ne0$ such that
$$
a^Tx \ge a^T y \quad \forall x\in X, y\in X^c.
$$
Define $j:=\inf_{x\in X} a^Tx$. Then the hyperplace $H:=\{ z:\ a^Tz = j\}$ separates
$X$ and $X^c$.

Let $z$ be a boundary point of $X$ then there are sequences $x_k \to z$ in $X$ and $y_k\to z$ in $X^c$. Then $a^Tx_k \ge j \ge a^Ty_k$ and passing to the limit implies $z\in H$.