# if $F(x,y)>0$ is convex and $1/F$ is convex show that up to a rotation $F(x,y) = F(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis

Let

$$F \; : \; \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$$
be a strictly positive function such that $F, \frac{1}{F}$ are both convex.
Show that there is a function
$$g \; : \; \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
and a vector
$$v \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
such that
$$F(x) = g(v\cdot x) \;\; \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

I have found a solution to this exercise but I'm not satisfied because it uses the extra assumption that $F \in C^2$ and $\nabla F$ is never $\underline{0}$, I would like to find an easier solution that doesn't rely on these extra assumptions.

This is my solution :

I will assume $F \in C^2$ and $\nabla F$ is always non-zero.

First a bit of notation :

I use the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ thus I identify matrices with biliniear forms, if $A$ is a ($2 \times 2$) matrix by $A \geq 0$ I mean

$$(Ax,x) \geq 0 \;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

by $A \leq B$ I mean $B - A \geq 0$, or equivalently

$$(Ax,x) \leq (Bx,x) \;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

I claim that

if $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $B$ is any matrix such that
$0 \leq A \leq B$

then $\ker(B) \subset \ker(A)$

To show it observe that, since $A$ is symmetric, up to a rotation I can assume it is diagonal,so there are $\lambda,\mu \geq 0$ so that
$$
  A=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
    \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & \mu \\
  \end{array} } \right)
  $$

then if $B v = 0$ and $v = (v_1,v_2)$ I find

$0 \leq \lambda (v_1)^2 + \mu(v_2)^2 \leq 0$

which clearly implies $\lambda v_1 = \mu v_2 = 0$ so $A v = 0$

which shows the claim

Now back to the exercise

I assume $F \in C^2$, thus $1/F \in C^2$ and so convexity implies $\nabla^2 F \geq 0$, $\nabla^2 1/F \geq 0$.

I calculate $\nabla^2 \frac{1}{F}$

\begin{equation}\nabla^2 \frac{1}{F} = \frac{2}{F^3}\nabla F \otimes \nabla F - \frac{1}{F^2}\nabla^2 F \geq 0\end{equation}

from this I easily find

\begin{equation} 0 \leq \nabla^2 F \leq \frac{2}{F} (\nabla F \otimes \nabla F) \end{equation}

so using the previous claim $\ker(\nabla F \otimes \nabla F) \subset \ker(\nabla^2 F)$

but clearly $\ker(\nabla F) \subset \ker(\nabla F \otimes \nabla F)$.

Now let $$\mathcal{N}(x,y,\underline{v}) = 
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
  \nabla F(x,y)\cdot \underline{v}  \\
  \underline{v} \cdot \underline{v} - 1 \\
\end{array} } \right) $$

I want to use implicit differentiation theorem to find $v = v(x,y)$, so I differentiate $\mathcal{N}$ with respect to $v$

$$\nabla_{\underline{v}}{\mathcal{N}} = 
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
  \nabla F(x,y)  \\
  2\underline{v} \\
\end{array} } \right) $$

by definition if $\mathcal{N}(x,y,\underline{v}) = 0$ then the two vectors are orthogonal and they are both non-zero thus $\nabla_{\underline{v}}{\mathcal{N}}$ is invertible and

$$\nabla_{x,y}{\underline{v}} = (\nabla_{\underline{v}}{\mathcal{N}})^{-1}( \nabla_{x,y}{\mathcal{N}})$$

but I have that

$$\nabla_{x,y}{\mathcal{N}} =  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
  \nabla^2F(x,y) \cdot v  \\
  \underline{0} \\
\end{array} }  \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
  \underline{0}  \\
  \underline{0} \\
\end{array} }  \right) $$ and here I'm using $\underline{v} \in \ker{\nabla F} \subset \ker{\nabla^2 F}$

thus $\nabla_{x,y}{\underline{v}} = 0$.

Now fix $\underline{w}$ so that it has norm $1$ and $\nabla F(0,0) \cdot \underline{w} = 0$, Let $U := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; : \; \mathcal{N}(x,y,w) = 0\}$.\

The set is nonempty since $(0,0) \in U$, and by what we have shown the set is open, therefore it's $U =\mathbb{R}^2$, but this shows that $\nabla F(x,y) \cdot w = 0$ for all $(x,y)$ and this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Overview:* The idea of the following proof is to show that the sublevel sets
$$
 S(c) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 \mid F(x) \le c\} \, .
$$
are empty, or the entire plane, or closed halfplanes of the form
$$
 S(c) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 \mid v \cdot x \le h_c \}
$$
with a common normal vector $v \in \Bbb R^2$. Then $F$ is constant on the boundary of $S(c)$ and therefore determined by its values on the line $L = \{t v \mid t \in \Bbb R \}$, i.e.
$$
F(x) = F((v \cdot x) v)
$$
where $x' = (v \cdot x) v$ is the projection of $x$ onto the line $L$. Finally define $g(t) = f(tv)$ to get the desired representation $F(x) =  g(v \cdot x)$.

---

And now the details: For $c > 0$ let $S(c) \subset \Bbb R^2$ be the sublevel set
$$
 S(c) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 \mid F(x) \le c\} \, .
$$
$S(c)$ is closed because $F$ is continuous (see for example [Continuity of a convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216778/42969)).

The key observation is that both $S(c)$ and its complement are convex sets, and that is because both $F$ and $1/F$ are convex functions. If $S(c)$ is not empty or the entire plane then its boundary is a line (see for example [If a set $X$ is convex and its complement $X^c$ is convex, then the boundary is a hyperplane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3481411/42969)).

It follows that each set $S(c)$ is either empty, a (closed) halfplane, or equal to $\Bbb R^2$. (*Remark:* It is not difficult to show that the cases $S(c) = \emptyset$ and $S(c) = \Bbb R^2$ can only happen if $F$ is constant. But that is not needed for this proof.)

If $c > 0$ is such that $S(c)$ is neither the empty set nor the entire plane then
$$
 S(c) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 \mid v_c \cdot x \le h_c \}
$$
with some unit vector $v_c \in \Bbb R^2$ and some $h_c \in \Bbb R$.

If $0 < c < d$ are both such that $S(c)$ and $S(c)$ are neither the empty set nor the entire plane then $S(c) \subset S(d)$ and therefore $v_c =  v_d$. It follows that
$$
 S(c) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 \mid v \cdot x \le h_c \}
$$
with a *common* unit vector $v \in \Bbb R^2$ for all $c$ for which $S(c)$ is not empty or the entire plane.

For $x \in \Bbb R^2$ is $x' = (v \cdot x)v$ the projection of $x$ onto the line $\{ t v \mid t \in \Bbb R\}$ with $v \cdot x' = v \cdot x$. It follows that
$$
 \forall c > 0 \, : \quad F(x) \le c \iff F((v \cdot x)v) \le c
$$
and therefore
$$
 F(x) = F((v \cdot x)v) = g(v \cdot x)
$$
where $g: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is defined as $g(t) = f(tv)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Reference*. Boyd and Vandenberghe, "Convex optimization",
page 122, Exercise 3.46;
[http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

Since $F > 0$, $F$ and $1/F$ are both convex,
we know that $F$ is continuous quasilinear.

According the reference, there is a monotone function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) = g(a^T x)$.

The proof from the solution manual:
[image]